# Problems converting WAV to ALAC by a batch job

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, conversion, wav

I use the following code to convert WAV to ALAC (bash, macOS 10.12.1):

```
find . -type f -iname "*.wav" | while read fn; do ffmpeg -i "$fn" -acodec alac "${fn%.wav}.m4a"; done
```

But there seems to be a mistake since it prints warnings like this:

```
n---8085/03_Part_III.wav: No such file or directory
```

The correct path would be:

```
Bad_Religion/wav/Bad_Religion---8085/03_Part_III.wav
```

For some reason the path is truncated.

What's wrong with the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file names are not actually being truncated.  Here, `ffmpeg` is trying to read commands from its input stream.  Unfortunately, this is the same stream `read` is using to determine filenames, so it appears that parts of these filenames are not being read.  To fix this, you should tell `ffmpeg` to disable interaction on the input stream with the `-nostdin` flag.